COM STA Exe Server CoWaitForMultipleHandles in detached thread: How does it work?
Trying to implement an IThumbnailProvider, and came across this example:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/CloudMirror/CloudMirror/ShellServices.cpp
Some questions:

AFAIK the behavior for detached std::threads when the program exits is unspecified (or UB? not sure); is this example depending on some Windows implementation detail? Would the class object eventually be properly  revoked in this case? Does it have anything to do with this part of CoWaitForMultipleHandles's docs?

If the caller resides in a single-thread apartment, CoWaitForMultipleHandles enters the COM modal loop, and the thread's message loop will continue to dispatch messages using the thread's message filter.


Why COWAIT_DISPATCH_CALLS if it only works in Application STA? Does it mean that in this case it's equivalent to COWAIT_DEFAULT?


Edit:
So from my own testing whatever after the CoWaitForMultipleHandles won't be executed on program exit. So it does seem like that a detached STA thread would be simply terminated on process exit  (My thought was that perhaps if Windows detects a detached thread has a message loop then it'll first send WM_QUIT to allow graceful exit). In this case would the COM resources be properly cleaned up at all (things like pumping remaining COM messages)? Oldnewthing states that MTA does automatically clean up when the last MTA thread exits, what about STA then, considering that in this case the STA thread is detached and apparently forcefully killed?

As documented: "COWAIT_DISPATCH_CALLS: This value has no meaning in other apartment types and is ignored." So yes, if you specify this flag in anything other than an ASTA it is as if you had specified no flags at all (which is the same as COWAIT_DEFAULT).

This is a shortcut taken by the sample: It is lazy and doesn't bother cleaning up the server on exit. Probably should be fixed.
